# Convert Varchar to decimals in crystal report

Tags: string, visual-studio, if-statement, crystal-reports, report

```
if {spFMGenerateSubReportB;1.BendNo} > 0 then 

(totext({spFMGenerateSubReportB;1.SheetTotal} * {spFMGenerateSubReportB;1.BendNo}, 0) )

else 
""
```

When i saved this formula in crystal report. It says a string is required here.
Does anyone know how to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect either {spFMGenerateSubReportB;1.SheetTotal} or {spFMGenerateSubReportB;1.BendNo} are non-numeric fields. Probably contains a alpha or punctuation mark somewhere in the field. This formula should help you vet that out if it is the case

```
if isnumeric({spFMGenerateSubReportB;1.SheetTotal}) and isnumeric({spFMGenerateSubReportB;1.BendNo}) then
    if tonumber({spFMGenerateSubReportB;1.SheetTotal})>0 then
        (totext(tonumber({spFMGenerateSubReportB;1.SheetTotal})*tonumber({spFMGenerateSubReportB;1.BendNo}),0) )
    else ""
else "NonNumeric"
```